# creating a binary variable in RStudio

Tags: r, variables

I am using the following code in R to create a new variable called `success` in my dataset (`leaders`)

`leaders$success <- as.numeric(leaders$result == 'dies within a day after the attack','dies between a day and a week','dies between a week and a month','dies, timing unknown')`

It happens that the code above only compute the variable `dies within a day after the attack`. How should a rephrase the code in order to compute the other three variables? I tried using the `OR` operator, `|` but It is possible only for numeric arguments.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Are you looking for `%in%` instead of `==` ? Like `1 %in% c(1,2,3)`? 'Or', as `|`, is definitely not only for numeric arguments either. It will combine any logical comparison `"a" == "b" | 1 == 1` for instance.

Comment: Please include a reproducible question as suggested here [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) include your data (as a dataframe object or use dput("yourdata"), the code you have tried and your expected output. This will make it more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: when I use ```leaders$success <- as.numeric(leaders$result ==  "dies within a day after the attack" | "dies between a day and a week" | "dies between a week and a month" | "dies, timing unknown")``` It shows the following error: "operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"

Comment: `leaders$success <- as.numeric(leaders$result %in% c('dies within a day after the attack','dies between a day and a week','dies between a week and a month','dies, timing unknown'))`

Comment: Yep, to provide further info: you are unintentionally doing  `"string" | "other string"`. However, `|` and `&` are for making `logical` comparisons like `TRUE | FALSE` and `TRUE & TRUE`. Character strings have no way of being considered as `TRUE` or `FALSE` so R gives an error.

Comment: Ronak solved the problem I was facing. Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` is used for element-wise comparison, if you want to compare multiple values use `%in%` and turn the values to numeric/integer.

```
leaders$success <- as.integer(leaders$result %in% 
   c('dies within a day after the attack','dies between a day and a week',
   'dies between a week and a month','dies, timing unknown'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `+` to coerce the logical to binary

```
leaders$success <- +(leaders$result %in% 
  c('dies within a day after the attack','dies between a day and a week',
   'dies between a week and a month','dies, timing unknown'))
```